# Installing wxPython in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: python, ubuntu, wxpython

I am trying to install wxPython on my Ubuntu 12.10 but with no success. I have gone through all the answers given on this website.
Can someone please help me in this or point me in the right direction.

Initially, I tried http://wxpython.org/BUILD.html but then I came to know that it is in the repository, I ran "`sudo apt-get install install python-wxgtk2.8`", it installed without any error but then, when I run it, it is still unavailable. I guess I am doing something in the running step.

Also, although it is working in Eclipse using PyDev, but I am getting this warning " `LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.`"" after I close the application and the status bar is also not working,

Here is my code:

```
import wx

class naman(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):  # @ReservedAssignment
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Frame aka Window', size=(300,200))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)

        statusbar=self.CreateStatusBar()
        menubar=wx.MenuBar()
        first=wx.Menu()
        second=wx.Menu()
        first.Append(wx.NewId(),"New Window", "This opens a new window")
        first.Append(wx.NewId(),"Open...", "This will open")
        second.Append(wx.NewId(),"Undo", "This will undo")
        second.Append(wx.NewId(),"Redo", "This will redo")
        menubar.Append(first,"File")
        menubar.Append(second,"Edit")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
    if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=naman(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

If someone can tell why I am getting this warning and why status bar is not working, that would be great too!! Then, I can continue working in eclipse itself and don't bother about wxPython.

PS: I have Python2.7 and Python3.3 already installed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What answers did you try and how exactly didn't it work? Please [add more detail](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17261975/edit) to your question.

Comment: Are you using the correct version of Python? As I understand it, wxPython does not yet support Python 3.

Comment: wxPython's Phoenix project is compatible with Python 3, but it's not complete yet. There's still a lot of widgets to port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install wxPython Phoenix, not 2.8. The 2.8 series and the 2.9 Classic series are only Python 2.x compatible. You'll have to grab a Phoenix snapshot to build against as it is the only version that is Python 3 compatible. You can get one here:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/

Note that Phoenix is very beta in that it only supports the core widgets currently. Most of the custom widgets, like those in wx.lib, are still being ported. See http://wiki.wxpython.org/ProjectPhoenix for more information.